# kdenlive no audio in rendered video

Tags: audio, kdenlive

operating system: ubuntu 22

kdenlive version: 21.12.3

Audio is available in editing mode and can be played, however, after the project is rendered/exported into a file, video is fine but there is no audio.

The attached screenshot shows the rendering configuration:

[image: rendering configuration]

How can I resolve the issue?